# jQuery string replace very special characters

Tags: php, jquery

I have a PHP JSON encoded string like this:-

SAINT JOHN\'S

and I would like to change it to

SAINT JOHN'S in jQuery scripts.

I tried:-

```
data[i].name.replace("[\']","'");
data[i].name.replace(/\'/g,"'");
```

all still give me SAINT JOHN\'S. how can I deal with the special character replacement?

Comment: `data[i].name.replace("\\","");`

Comment: When you decode the JSON, it should remove the backslashes, so you shouldn't need to do this. Can you show your code that's receiving the JSON from PHP?

Comment: it works! why don't you paste it as answer and I give you a tick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the *backslash* `\` before *single quote* `'` as well.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cDVy4/)**

```
data[i].name.replace(/\\\'/g,"'")
```

You can replace \ with empty string but it could replace other back slash as well.

Comment: For the records: this answers the question, but I suspect the OP made the wrong question. There're many ways to decode JSON (from builtin decoder to third-party libraries) and I can't think of any circumstance where you need to strip the backslash from single quote, unless the data is already corrupted when it reaches the browser.